# How to use Initiate while destroying object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to write code that allows me to tap on object and destroy it and when it disappears, explosion effect plays once on destroyed object's position or new object spawns where previous object was.

I have tried to look for some tutorials on how to code "click object" function and destroy it. I was able to do that but I wasn't able to spawn anything.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class IceTile : MonoBehaviour
{
internal Vector3 m_MyTravelPoint;
private void Start()
{
    m_MyTravelPoint = transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0.61f, 0);
}
private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
{
    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(m_MyTravelPoint, 0.5f);
}
void Update()
{

}
void OnMouseDown()
{
    // this object was clicked - do something

    object Eff_Heal_2_oneShot = null;
    Instatiate(Eff_Heal_2_oneShot, transform.position, 
Quaternion.identity, out hit);
    Destroy(this.gameObject);

}

private void Instatiate(object eff_Heal_2_oneShot, object position, 
Quaternion identity)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
}
```

I wanted this code to allow me to touch and delete object and cause explosion or spawn object but I wasn't successful.

Answer (score 0):

First, get rid of your custom `Instantiate` method. There's already a properly working `Instantiate` method on the object; you don't need to make another one.

Then, add a `public GameObject explosionEffect` field to the class. This will contain the explosion prefab that you want to spawn. In the scene inspector, drag the prefab to it.

Also, to detect mouse clicks using `OnMouseDown`, you will need to attach some kind of `Collider` component to the `IceTile`'s game object. You may have already done this. This can be done in the scene editor.

In `OnMouseDown` before you call `Destroy`, call `Instantiate` to spawn the explosion effect:

```
Instantiate (explosionEffect, transform.position);
```

Altogether this might look like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class IceTile : MonoBehaviour
{

    internal Vector3 m_MyTravelPoint;
    public GameObject explosionEffect;

    private void Start()
    {
        m_MyTravelPoint = transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0.61f, 0);
    }
    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(m_MyTravelPoint, 0.5f);
    }
    void Update()
    {

    }
    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        // this object was clicked - do something
        Instantiate(explosionEffect, transform.position);
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```